# Get response from core strapi apis by a field other than id

Tags: javascript, node.js, strapi

I have a collection type called `products` in strapi v4. I want to fetch a specific product by a field other than id. Right now i use the following route
`http://localhost:1337/api/products` and it gives response

```js
{
  "data": [{
      "id": 50,
      "attributes": {
        "name": "Tshirt",
        "createdAt": "2023-07-03T14:21:31.155Z",
        "updatedAt": "2023-07-03T14:21:31.155Z",
        "publishedAt": "2023-07-03T14:21:31.154Z",
        "unique_id": "urn:uuid:fff28733-504e-4065-8938-2b3966a9b6ec"
      }
    },
    {
      "id": 51,
      "attributes": {
        "name": "Sweater",
        "createdAt": "2023-07-03T15:41:52.546Z",
        "updatedAt": "2023-07-03T15:41:54.017Z",
        "publishedAt": "2023-07-03T15:41:54.014Z",
        "unique_id": "abc"
      }
    }
  ],
  "meta": {
    "pagination": {
      "page": 1,
      "pageSize": 25,
      "pageCount": 1,
      "total": 2
    }
  }
}
```

I want to fetch a specific product by the `unique_id` parameter. How can i do this?